# How to format ESLint rules for running prettier-eslint programmatically?

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier

I have copied my .eslintrc.json and .prettierrc.json to ESLINT and PRETTIER variables, and plugged it into `prettier-eslint`'s formatter. But it is giving me TypeScript errors which I don't understand.

```
import format from 'prettier-eslint'

const PRETTIER = {
  arrowParens: "avoid" as const,
  bracketSpacing: true,
  endOfLine: "lf" as const,
  importOrder: ["^\\w(.*)$", "^@(.*)$", "~(.*)$", "\\..(.*)$", "\\.(.*)$"],
  importOrderSeparation: true,
  importOrderSortSpecifiers: true,
  printWidth: 72,
  proseWrap: "always" as const,
  quoteProps: "as-needed" as const,
  semi: false,
  singleAttributePerLine: true,
  singleQuote: true,
  tabWidth: 2,
  trailingComma: "all" as const,
  useTabs: false,
};

const ESLINT = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: ["prettier"],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest" as const,
    project: [`${__dirname}/tsconfig.json`],
    sourceType: "module" as const,
  },
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
    "simple-import-sort",
    "sort-exports",
    "typescript-sort-keys",
    "sort-keys",
    "prettier",
  ],
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/array-type": [
      2,
      {
        default: "generic",
      },
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/await-thenable": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": [2, "type"],
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-exports": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/lines-between-class-members": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/method-signature-style": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-array-constructor": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-for-in-array": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-useless-empty-export": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/object-curly-spacing": [2, "always"],
    "@typescript-eslint/padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      {
        blankLine: "always",
        next: ["type"],
        prev: "*",
      },
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-function-type": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
      "error",
      "single",
      {
        allowTemplateLiterals: true,
        avoidEscape: true,
      },
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/space-before-blocks": ["error", "always"],
    "@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing": ["error", { after: true }],
    curly: 2,
    "default-case": "error",
    "default-case-last": "error",
    "import/first": "error",
    "import/newline-after-import": "error",
    "import/no-duplicates": "error",
    "lines-between-class-members": "off",
    "no-array-constructor": "off",
    "no-throw-literal": "off",
    "object-curly-spacing": "off",
    "padding-line-between-statements": "off",
    "prettier/prettier": 2,
    "sort-exports/sort-exports": ["error", { sortDir: "asc" }],
    "sort-keys": 0,
    "sort-keys/sort-keys-fix": 2,
    "space-before-blocks": "off",
    "typescript-sort-keys/interface": "error",
    "typescript-sort-keys/string-enum": "error",
  },
};

function makeText(text: string) {
  const config = {
    eslintConfig: ESLINT,
    prettierOptions: PRETTIER,
    text: text,
  };
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
  return format(config) as string;
}
```

What is wrong with my approach? Why isn't it accepting my default ESLint rules from my .eslintrc.json? How can I get this to work? I am trying to run my eslint + prettier cleanup programmatically, to automatically format some generated code.

I am getting:

```
Argument of type '{ eslintConfig: { env: { browser: boolean; es2021: boolean; }; extends: string[]; parser: string; parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: "latest"; project: string[]; sourceType: "module"; }; plugins: string[]; rules: { '@typescript-eslint/array-type': (number | { default: string; })[]; '@typescript-eslint/await-thenable': string; '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions': (string | number)[]; '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-exports': string; '@typescript-eslint/lines-between-class-members': string; '@typescript-eslint/method-signature-style': string; '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': number; '@typescript-eslint/no-array-constructor': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-for-in-array': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-namespace': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition': number; '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-useless-empty-export': string; '@typescript-eslint/object-curly-spacing': (string | number)[]; '@typescript-eslint/padding-line-between-statements': (string | { blankLine: string; next: string[]; prev: string; })[]; '@typescript-eslint/prefer-function-type': string; '@typescript-eslint/quotes': (string | { allowTemplateLiterals: boolean; avoidEscape: boolean; })[]; '@typescript-eslint/space-before-blocks': string[]; '@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing': (string | { after: boolean; })[]; curly: number; 'default-case': string; 'default-case-last': string; 'import/first': string; 'import/newline-after-import': string; 'import/no-duplicates': string; 'lines-between-class-members': string; 'no-array-constructor': string; 'no-throw-literal': string; 'object-curly-spacing': string; 'padding-line-between-statements': string; 'prettier/prettier': number; 'sort-exports/sort-exports': (string | { sortDir: string; })[]; 'sort-keys': number; 'sort-keys/sort-keys-fix': number; 'space-before-blocks': string; 'typescript-sort-keys/interface': string; 'typescript-sort-keys/string-enum': string; }; }; prettierOptions: { arrowParens: "avoid"; bracketSpacing: boolean; endOfLine: "lf"; importOrder: string[]; importOrderSeparation: boolean; importOrderSortSpecifiers: boolean; printWidth: number; proseWrap: "always"; quoteProps: "as-needed"; semi: boolean; singleAttributePerLine: boolean; singleQuote: boolean; tabWidth: number; trailingComma: "all"; useTabs: boolean; }; text: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.
  The types of 'eslintConfig.rules' are incompatible between these types.
    Type '{ '@typescript-eslint/array-type': (number | { default: string; })[]; '@typescript-eslint/await-thenable': string; '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions': (string | number)[]; '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-exports': string; '@typescript-eslint/lines-between-class-members': string; '@typescript-eslint/method-signature-style': string; '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': number; '@typescript-eslint/no-array-constructor': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-for-in-array': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-namespace': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition': number; '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': string; '@typescript-eslint/no-useless-empty-export': string; '@typescript-eslint/object-curly-spacing': (string | number)[]; '@typescript-eslint/padding-line-between-statements': (string | { blankLine: string; next: string[]; prev: string; })[]; '@typescript-eslint/prefer-function-type': string; '@typescript-eslint/quotes': (string | { allowTemplateLiterals: boolean; avoidEscape: boolean; })[]; '@typescript-eslint/space-before-blocks': string[]; '@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing': (string | { after: boolean; })[]; curly: number; 'default-case': string; 'default-case-last': string; 'import/first': string; 'import/newline-after-import': string; 'import/no-duplicates': string; 'lines-between-class-members': string; 'no-array-constructor': string; 'no-throw-literal': string; 'object-curly-spacing': string; 'padding-line-between-statements': string; 'prettier/prettier': number; 'sort-exports/sort-exports': (string | { sortDir: string; })[]; 'sort-keys': number; 'sort-keys/sort-keys-fix': number; 'space-before-blocks': string; 'typescript-sort-keys/interface': string; 'typescript-sort-keys/string-enum': string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<RulesRecord>'.
      Property ''@typescript-eslint/array-type'' is incompatible with index signature.
        Type '(number | { default: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'RuleEntry<any[]> | undefined'.
          Type '(number | { default: string; })[]' is not assignable to type '[_: RuleLevel, ..._1: any[]]'.
            Source provides no match for required element at position 0 in target.
```

Comment: You can open arg types for `format()`, look for `eslintConfig` and `prettierOptions`. Then cast `ESLINT` as TypeThatYouFoundFromEslintFormatConfig and see what is the acceptable and what do you pass wrongly.